# Link two D3 plots

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to link two D3 plots so that selecting part of the histogram on the right, causes a certain scatter plot to display on the left.

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fn5y95m4n3pcy8/visualization.html) is my attempt.

My current question is why the right plot isn't rendering, which I think goes back to how to create and refer to multiple SVG tags in d3.

Answer (score 3):

D3 has SVG controls for this type of situation. What you are looking for is a brush with context.

Here are the API docs:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls

And here are two great examples:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

Comment: Another nice example which does brush on hover (without selection) is http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/6641917