# Positioning two D3 plots

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to position two plots in a 2 by 1 column using in D3.

The first plot is a scatter plot and the second plot is a histogram. Eventually, the data shown on one will depend on the region selected in the other. Right now, I'm having problems positioning the two plots.

My [attempt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fn5y95m4n3pcy8/visualization.html).

Why do the two plots overlap?

I tried changing the "transform" attribute of the histogram (`var histo`) to account for the width of the first figure, but that just made the histogram disappear.

Comment: It would be much easier to troubleshoot your problem if you presented a working example of your issue, say, on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/)

Comment: Follow the examples that I answered in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304335/link-two-d3-plots/18304459#18304459